# При обработке следующих пакетов произошли ошибки: oracle-java11-installer-local

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt-get

Почему то нормально java  не установилась в ubunt-e  18.

По сути, пакет oracle-java11-installer-local, как то "заблокировал" менеджер пакетов и теперь даже "другие" пакеты не могу становить, что делать ??

```
dima@komp:~$ sudo apt-get install alien
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
Уже установлен пакет alien самой новой версии (8.95).
Следующие пакеты устанавливались автоматически и больше не требуются:
  gconf-service gconf-service-backend gconf2-common libgconf-2-4 libllvm7
  libllvm7:i386
  libmono-system-runtime-interopservices-runtimeinformation4.0-cil
  libnunit-cil-dev libnunit-console-runner2.6.3-cil
  libnunit-core-interfaces2.6.3-cil libnunit-core2.6.3-cil
  libnunit-framework2.6.3-cil libnunit-mocks2.6.3-cil libnunit-util2.6.3-cil
  libreadline5 libsdl-ttf2.0-0 mariadb-common mono-jay
Для их удаления используйте «sudo apt autoremove».
Обновлено 0 пакетов, установлено 0 новых пакетов, для удаления отмечено 0 пакетов, и 235 пакетов не обновлено.
Установлено или удалено не до конца 1 пакетов.
После данной операции объём занятого дискового пространства возрастёт на 0 B.
Хотите продолжить? [Д/н] Y
Настраивается пакет oracle-java11-installer-local (11.0.6-2~linuxuprising0) …
Before installing this package,
please download the Oracle JDK 11 .tar.gz file
with the same version as this package (version 11.0.4),
and place it in /var/cache/oracle-jdk11-installer-local,

E.g.:
sudo mkdir -p /var/cache/oracle-jdk11-installer-local
sudo cp jdk-11.0.4_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz /var/cache/oracle-jdk11-installer-local/
sha256sum mismatch jdk-11.0.6_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
Oracle JDK 11 is NOT installed.
dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета oracle-java11-installer-local (--configure):
 installed oracle-java11-installer-local package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
При обработке следующих пакетов произошли ошибки:
 oracle-java11-installer-local
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо поочередно выполнить эти команды :

```
sudo rm -rf /var/cache/oracle-jdk11-installer-local

sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/oracle*
sudo apt purge oracle-java11-installer*
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*java*
sudo apt autoremove
```

---

*По сути вопрос является вольным переводом этого [вопроса](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1175624/how-can-i-remove-the-package-oracle-java11-installer-local).*